# No way of starting Quartz on server deploy

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, quartz-scheduler, jboss5.x

I am struggling this for a week.
using Jboss5.1.x, EJB3.0, quartz1.8
people refer me to to documents, but it seems like no1 has really clue or doesn't understand me.

Is there a way of starting the java code in EJB bean to schedule quartz?
I already understood how to init and loop up the quartz scheduler.. but how do you actually call the method which INIT the scheduler on application deployment?

if you need the JBOSS scheduler to first call the init method which schedule Quartz, then Quartz is useless for me! i would just continue with Jboss scheduler.

anyone has any solution for that?

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but What I wanted to achive is to have my quartz start on deploy. but I found solution for this I am using

```
@Service(objectName = "..")
@Management(...)
```

and that class will be triggerd as soon as my project will deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question but can't you store the Quartz scheduler factory in a static variable and initialize it in a static initializer or a static method? Something like:

```
public static Scheduler sched;

public static void init(ServletContext servletContext) throws SchedulerException {
    if (sched == null || !sched.isStarted()) {
        String quartzPropertiesLocation = UtilityClass.getYourQuartzConfig();
        try {
            log.info(new File(quartzPropertiesLocation).getCanonicalPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SchedulerFactory schedFact = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory(quartzPropertiesLocation);
        sched = schedFact.getScheduler();
        sched.getContext().put(ServletContext.class.getName(), servletContext);
        sched.start();
    }
}
```